# Best way to calculate over a large data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find best way to handle a dataset around 80 million rows.
I need to make some calculations over this data. I am trying `for` loops but takes like forever.

I have data as below (individual taxi trips from one area to another, resolution of 15 minutes):

```
timestamp,        origin_area, destination_area

2014-01-27 11:00:00, 28.0,        32.0

2014-01-27 11:00:00, 28.0,        32.0

2013-01-01 01:00:00, 28.0,        1.0

2013-01-01 01:15:00, 28.0,        2.0
```

I need to convert this data into some columns like this:

timestamp, 
origin_area, 
destination_area, 
(sum of trips for distinct origin-destination couples in that timestamp), 
(sum of all trips from origin area in that timestamp)

What are my options to fastly handle these calculations and creating additional columns as above?

Thank you

Comment: are you using pandas dataframe?

Comment: It would be nice if you first try it yourself and then tell us were you got stuck.

Comment: yes i am using pandas.

Comment: df_pivoted = df.pivot_table(index=['trip_start_timestamp','pickup_community_area','dropoff_community_area'],
               values=['total_trips'],
               aggfunc='count')

i pivoted df like above.

Comment: @Alper can you provide data with all variables necessary to make calculation ? I see you are using other variables which aren't shown in the table above. Few rows will suffice:)

Answer (score 0):

I got [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [size()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) to do this.

```
df.groupby(['timestamp', 'origin_area','destination_area']).size().reset_index(name='Count').sort_values(by="timestamp", 
                                                                            ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

;)